# Python - getting "string indices must be integers" while using json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, for-loop

I want to iterate through this array of objects and put values inside the array into variables.
My code looks like this:

```py
    my_event = {"headers":{},
    'httpMethod': 'POST', 'body': {"letter":"A",
    "arr_of_obj":[{"One":"first","Two":"Second"}]}}

    my_event_arr = json.dumps(my_event["body"])
    
    for i in my_event_arr["arr_of_obj"]:
        num_one = i["One"]
        num two = i["Two"]
```

This is not my code, but a representation of what I want to achieve. When I try to do this, I get this error:

> string indices must be integers

How can I fix this?

Comment: That isn't valid Python.  You need curly braces, not square braces: `"arr_of_obj": {"One":"first","Two":"Second"}}}`.

Comment: `json.dumps()` returns a string.  Therefore `my_event_arr` is a string.  But it seems like you're expecting it to be a dict.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for pointing out , it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps()` results in a string. String cannot be indexed using string.

Why do you need to do `json.dumps()` there? `my_event` is already a `dict`, you can use that directly?

Edit: Also, as what @TimRoberts said in his comment. Please use the correct type of braces.